# How can you do an SVN checkout on the basis of a specific project ID/artifact ID?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

How can you do an SVN checkout on the basis of a specific project ID/artifact ID?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in concept of "project ID" or "artifact ID" in Subversion or TortoiseSVN.

- If by "project ID" you mean a project, then maybe it can be tied to a repository path and URL such as `https://svn.example.com/repos/MyProject`.
- If by "artifact ID" you mean some kind of ticket for a developer, I guess that there should be a branch for this work. It can also be addressed by an URL such as `https://svn.example.com/repos/MyProject/branches/MyArtifactBranch`.

I would recommend that you read the documentation:

- [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is a great resource of information about Subversion and version control in general. It will help you familiarize yourself with common terminology and concepts of SVN and version control. Now your questions are a bit unclear.
- [TortoiseSVN manual](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html) will help you gain knowledge of the GUI client and perform most common SVN operations with its help.